Можно ли добавить один узел в дерево так, чтобы дерево осталось деревом бинарного поиска и стало сбалансированным?
Задача: проверить, можно ли добавить один узел в дерево так, чтобы дерево осталось деревом бинарного поиска и стало сбалансированным (определить допустимое значение добавляемого узла);
А. Я попытался решить ее следующим образом:

Проверять может дерево вообще уже сбалансировано и ничего не надо добавлять
Идти вниз до уровня пока не обнаружу дисбаланс
Добавлять узел и проверять сбалансированность.
Вот методы, которые я добавил в самодельный класс Tree (заранее говорю, что все методы (такие как Добавление, Обходы и т.п. работают корректно)

            public void CheckAndBalanceTree()
            {
                if (Root == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Дерево пустое.");
                    return;
                }

                if (IsBalanced(Root))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Дерево уже сбалансировано.");
                    return;
                }

                bool treeBalanced = false;
                T optimalValue = default;
                Node<T> currentNode = Root;

                while (!treeBalanced)
                {
                    int imbalanceLevel = GetImbalanceLevel(Root);

                    if (imbalanceLevel == -1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Ошибка: Дерево не удалось сбалансировать даже после добавления узла.");
                        return;
                    }

                    if (currentNode.AddForBalancing(optimalValue, out optimalValue))
                    {
                        treeBalanced = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        currentNode = FindNodeAtLevel(Root, imbalanceLevel);
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Дерево сбалансировано добавлением узла со значением: " + optimalValue);
            }

        private bool IsBalanced(Node<T> root)
        {
            if (root == null)
            {
                return true;
            }

            Queue<Node<T>> queue = new Queue<Node<T>>();
            queue.Enqueue(root);

            while (queue.Count > 0)
            {
                Node<T> current = queue.Dequeue();

                if (Math.Abs(GetHeight(current.Left) - GetHeight(current.Right)) > 1)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                if (current.Left != null)
                {
                    queue.Enqueue(current.Left);
                }

                if (current.Right != null)
                {
                    queue.Enqueue(current.Right);
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        public int GetImbalanceLevel(Node<T> node)
            {
                if (node == null)
                {
                    return 0;
                }

                int leftHeight = GetImbalanceLevel(node.Left);
                int rightHeight = GetImbalanceLevel(node.Right);

                if (leftHeight == -1 || rightHeight == -1 || Math.Abs(leftHeight - rightHeight) > 1)
                {
                    return node.Height;
                }

                return Math.Max(leftHeight, rightHeight) + 1;
            }

            private Node<T> FindNodeAtLevel(Node<T> node, int targetLevel)
            {
                if (node == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                if (node.Height == targetLevel)
                {
                    return node;
                }

                Node<T> leftNode = FindNodeAtLevel(node.Left, targetLevel);
                Node<T> rightNode = FindNodeAtLevel(node.Right, targetLevel);

                return leftNode ?? rightNode;
            }

Я не прошу решить задачу вместо меня, но если честно я не могу придумать даже примерный алгоритм действий, и мне кажется что упомянутый выше план не верен. Как и мой код.
Я хочу узнать точный алгоритм, который позволит решить данную задачу, используя методы дерева бинарного поиска

Вы не приняли ни одного ответа на свои вопросы. Ознакомьтесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Какое определение сбалансироваанности  вы используете?

Сбалансированное дерево — такое, в котором все узлы, кроме конечных, имеют по два потомка, а все поддеревья одного уровня имеют одинаковую длину.
